# my smoke simulation doesn't render correctly in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

This is my smoke in eevee rendered viewport:

[image: evee viewport]

This is my smoke in cycles rendered viewport:

[image: cycles viewport]

When I rendered an image same thing happened.
I used only principled volume node and attach to volume.

[my .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/lgqOBRkB/)

Comment: hi and welcome to the forum! please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share .blend files

Comment: Ok i will do this today

Comment: İ couldn t find any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is empty space in smoke domain settings. it should be zero.